# save muliple value on selection of checkbox in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.3

I have two table First-taxonomy, second-product. 
relationship between both table- taxonomy hasMany product and product belongs to taxonomy.
I have to save many taxonomy id in product table on selection of checkbox.
Only selected checkbox value should save in product table.
[controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb8Tc.png)

[add.ctp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWKKl.png)

Answer (score 0):

For all checkbox give name as:

```
name="data['Product'][]['taxanomy_id']"
```

In your controller , within function add :

```
public function add() {
   $this->Product->create();
   if($this->Product->saveAll($this->request-data)){
      // saved
   }
}
```